# In iOS how to get current time like System.currentTimeMillis() in java?

Tags: ios, swift

In Java we use System.currentTimeMillis() to get time, is there similar method in iOS?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swift. It has to do with the system (e.g. iOS or OS X). And the way to find out the answer is to look in the documentation for that system.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use: 
`NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970`

"The interval between the date object and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970."

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about taking the time with miliseconds, I'd use `CACurrentMediaTime()`. Consider that the miliseconds are the fractional part.